# Vuejs2 - Iterate “tr” element recursively

Tags: recursion, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm pretty new to Vue and I love it so far. However, I've encountered the following problem and I'll be thankful for any suggestions on how to get around it.

I would like to iterate recursively on an objects to get a nested table.

I have this template:

```
<script type="text/x-template">
    <tr>
        <td><a v-on:click="toggle">[+]</a></td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr is="row-item"  v-show="open" ...></tr>
</script>
```

It's recursive, so each line `tr` has an other hidden line `tr` below.

When the user click on the [+] on the parent line, the children lines will appear.

I already try to wrap the content within a `tbody` tag, but then I get `tbody` inside `tbody`, which is still an illegal table layout and breaks it.

```
<script type="text/x-template">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr is="row-item" ...></tr>
    </tbody>
</script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rafi16d/puwcs9ay/

Vue@1.x doesn't require exactly one root element. How can I do without ?

Has anyone run into anything similar?

Thanks.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Recursive-Components

Comment: @EricGuan The docs indicate that it's possible to a component to invoke themselves in their own template and yes, it work. But the problem is that I cannot use multiple root element in my template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Sadly) Vue2 imperatively needs a real root element for each component.
So from that I think you don't have so many possibilities:

- Do two components instead of a single one, and iter both of them with a virtual node:

  ```
  <table>
      <tbody>
          <template for="row in someRows">
              <tr>mainRow</tr>
              <tr>subRow</tr>
          </template>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  ```
- Forget the idea to do a real table. Emulate the layout by using `<div>` and the [related display css properties](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) instead.

Comment: If someone has the same issue. I've forget the idea to use "table" element and I've use div elements. https://jsfiddle.net/rafi16d/whsbLn59/

Answer (score 1):

Alright i managed to do it. Red borders are for you to see the structure, you may want to adjust the padding.

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/puwcs9ay/9/

Several hacks, and ideas i borrowed from how jQuery Datatables does nested rows:

You can put pretty much anything in a `td`. So make the root element a `tr`, nest a `td` with colspan 100%, then you can nest a table. Since you can put `tr` inside of `table`, the recursion begins.

`tr` -> `td` -> `table` -> `tr` -> `td` -> `table`  ad infinitum

`<td colspan="42">`

42, or any number that's definitely higher than your column count, is basically equivalent to `colspan="100%"`.

You also can - and probably should - use the length of your array to give the `colspan` the correct number of columns, i was just lazy.

Inner `trs` have their default css changed.

```
.inner-tr{
    display: table;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your work. But they is a problem with your solution : the columns of the children doesn't match with the parent columns. So I think that I'm going to use two components instead of a single one. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you flatten the tree (normalize it) in a computed property, then you can render the HTML table without recursion within the component itself, and thus avoid hacking or generating invalid HTML.

```js
Vue.component('tree-table-row', {
  data() {
    return {
      indent: 20,
      left_padding: 5
    };
  },
  props: ['node'],
  template: '#tree-table-row'
}); 
      
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#tree-as-table',
  data: {
    tree: {
      id: 0,
      value: "fruits",
      name: "root",
      children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "A",
        children: [{
          id: 2,
          name: "B",
          value: "banana" 
        }],
        value: "apple"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "C",
        children: [{
          id: 4,
          name: "D",
          value: "durian" 
        }],
        value: "cherry"
      }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    tree_array() {
      return this.normalizedTree(this.tree, 0);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    normalizedTree(node, level) {
      var _this = this;
      var normal_element = {id: node.id, name: node.name, value: node.value, level: level};
      var array_fragment = [normal_element];
      if (node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
        var i;
        for (i=0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
          array_fragment = array_fragment.concat(_this.normalizedTree(node.children[i], level+1));
        };
      }
      return array_fragment;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.vue-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: sans-serif;
} 

td {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="tree-table-row">
  <tr>
    <td :style="{'padding-left': node.level * indent + left_padding + 'px'}">{{node.name}}</td>
    <td>{{node.value}}</td>
  </tr>
</script>
    
<div id="tree-as-table">
  <table class="vue-table">
    <tr is="tree-table-row" v-for="(node, index) in tree_array" :node="node" :key="node.id"/>
  </table>
</div>
```